# ReportViewer or CrystalReport?

Tags: crystal-reports, sql-server-ce, report, reportviewer

I'm working on a tiny windows application which has some select queries, I have just 3 tables in my SQL CE database. Considering the little size of the application is it worthy to use Crystal Reports? (and considering that it is not installed with VS 2010)
Guide me please.

Comment: What functionality do you need? How will you distribute your application?

Comment: it is a simple One user application, I just need simple functionality of printing reports with Join between three tables. that's it. I want to chose the easiest one because I am new in Report Viewing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try Crystal out. It's [a free download](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp) and it's pretty easy to create a basic report if you use the wizard.

For heavier business use I'm doubtful of Crystal, e.g. I'm not impressed with the way it handles images (it seems to leak memory). I have also had redistributions issues. But I think neither of these issues applies to your solution.